# R - which of these functions is giving the correct value of the integrals?

Tags: r, math

I am trying to compute this integral in R:

[image]

I found three functions which can be used for this and they are all giving me different results. Here is the code:

```
integrand <- function(x){
  r <- 1/x
  return(r)
}
```

First is the option from base R:

```
integrate(integrand,-Inf, Inf)
```

Giving the result:

```
0 with absolute error < 0
```

The second is from the `pracma` package:

```
quadinf(integrand, -Inf, Inf)
```

Giving this output:

```
$Q
[1] -106.227

$relerr
[1] 108.0135

$niter
[1] 7
```

And the last one is from the `cubature` package:

```
cubintegrate(integrand, -Inf, Inf)
```

Which gives the following result:

```
$integral
[1] Inf

$error
[1] NaN

$neval
[1] 15

$returnCode
[1] 0
```

So then, which one of these is correct and which should I trust? Is it 0, infinity, or -106.227? Why are they all different in the first place?

Comment: Can [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206032/what-is-the-integral-of-1-x) help?

Comment: 0 does [make some sense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887370/why-does-the-integral-of-1-x-diverge) actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1/x` isn't integrable in `[-Inf,Inf]` range, because not integrable in 0.

On an integrable range, results are similar:

```
integrate(\(x) 1/x,1,2)
#0.6931472 with absolute error < 7.7e-15

pracma::quadinf( \(x) 1/x,1,2)
#$Q
#[1] 0.6931472

#$relerr
#[1] 7.993606e-15

#$niter
#[1] 4
```

Note that integral of `1/x` in `]0,Inf]` range is `log(x)`:

```
log(2)-log(1)
#[1] 0.6931472
```

Comment: `1/sqrt(x)` is infinite for `x=0` but is integrable on `]0,1]`.